# How to communicate with Kafka server running inside a docker

Tags: networking, docker, apache-kafka

I am using apache KafkaConsumer in my Scala app to talk to a Kafka server wherein the Kafka and Zookeeper services are running in a docker container on my VM (the scala app is also running on this VM). I have setup the KafkaConsumer's property "bootstrap.servers" to use **127.0.0.1**:9092.

The KafkaConsumer does log, "Sending coordinator request for group queuemanager_testGroup to broker 127.0.0.1:9092". The problem appears to be that the Kafka client code is setting the coordinator values based on the response it receives which contains *responseBody={error_code=0,coordinator={node_id=0,host=**e7059f0f6580**,port=9092}}* , that is how it sets the host for future connections. Subsequently it complains that it is unable to resolve address: e7059f0f6580

The address e7059f0f6580 is the container ID of that docker container. 
I have tested using telnet that my VM is not detecting this as a hostname.

What setting do I need to change such that the Kafka on my docker returns localhost/127.0.0.1 as the host in its response  ? Or is there something else that I am missing / doing incorrectly ?

Comment: Well... the more relevant question is - "how are you running a containerised kafka service". Kafka needs zookeeper to work. And in general people use docker-compose to run the dependent containers. So... you will need to provide your Dockerfile, docker-compose.yaml or  the commands for starting these containers.

Comment: One more thing... please take some time to understand docker with something simpler such as a hello-world web application. And once you understand that you will understand the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

`advertised.host.name` is deprecated, and `--override` should be avoided.

Add/edit `advertised.listeners` to be the format of

```
[PROTOCOL]://[EXTERNAL.HOST.NAME]:[PORT]
```

Also make sure that `PORT` is also listed in property for `listeners`

---

After investigating this problem for hours on end, found that there is a way to 
set the hostname while starting up the Kafka server, as follows:
`kafka-server-start.sh --override advertised.host.name=xxx` (in my case: localhost)